# RSpec test model and mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have method in model

(User Model)

```
  def create_reset_code
      self.attributes = {:reset_code => Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( Time.now.to_s.split(//).sort_by {rand}.join )}
      save(:validate=>false)
      UserMailer.reset_password_email(self).deliver 
  end
```

How can I test it in RSpec? I want to test the code generation, and send e-mail

PS : using Google, but found no examples of

UPD

I write two tests:

```
it "should create reset code" do           
  @user.create_reset_code
  @user.reset_code.should_not be_nil
end    

it "should send reset code by email" do           
  @user.create_reset_code

  @email_confirmation = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.first
  @email_confirmation.to.should == [@user.email] 
  @email_confirmation.subject.should == I18n.t('emailer.pass_reset.subject')
  @email_confirmation.body.should match(/#{@user.reset_code}/)
end
```

But this ---  @email_confirmation.body.should match(/#{@user.reset_code}/) ---- don't work

In a letter I give url with reset_code as follow reset_password_url(@user.reset_code)

FIXED

```
it "should send reset code by email" do           
  @user.create_reset_code

  @email_confirmation = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  @email_confirmation.to.should == [@user.email] 
  @email_confirmation.subject.should == I18n.t('emailer.pass_reset.subject')
  @email_confirmation.html_part.body.should match /#{@user.reset_code}/
end
```

It's work!

Thank you all, question is closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
it "should create reset code" do           
  @user.create_reset_code
  @user.reset_code.should_not be_nil
end   


it "should send reset code by email" do           
  @user.create_reset_code

  @email_confirmation = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  @email_confirmation.to.should == [@user.email] 
  @email_confirmation.subject.should == I18n.t('emailer.pass_reset.subject')
  @email_confirmation.html_part.body.should match /#{@user.reset_code}/
end
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
```

to get the last email sent after calling that method on the spec, then you can do specs against mail.to or mail.body.raw_source

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how can I check the url with reset_code in the mail body?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help you.. I have used [Rspec matchers](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html)

```
it "should test your functionality" do
user = Factory(:ur_table, :name => 'xyz', :email => 'xyz@gmail.com')
obj = Factory(:ur_model_table)
key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( Time.now.to_s.split(//).sort_by {rand}.join
data = obj.create_reset_code
data.reset_code.should be(key)
let(:mail) {UserMailer.reset_password_email(user) }
mail.to.should be(user.email)
end
```

Comment: Error:  Failure/Error: data = User.create_reset_code
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create_reset_code'

Comment: I have edited the code as it is a instance method and should act on the object of that model so created a 'obj' Object and called creare_reset_code on it.